# LWJGL not working with Gradle - Linux ARM64 - Java 17

Tags: java, gradle, opengl, build.gradle, lwjgl

when trying to import LWJGL into my Java project using Gradle, i get the following error:

> org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find lwjgl-sse-3.3.0-natives-linux-arm64.jar (org.lwjgl:lwjgl-sse:3.3.0).

I have made sure that I've included LWJGL-sse in the dependencies

`runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-sse::$lwjglNatives"`

Comment: LWJGL SSE is not available on Linux arm64.